# How can I add automatic reference to All of Class , ... in my project?

Tags: c#, using

I have Dll that use all of project.
I add Dll to reference . When I need Dll I must use of code in head :

```
Using MyDlls;
```

How can I add MyDlls to all of class,... automatic ?

Comment: How can I do When I add reference then my reference add all of my project automatical?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking - are you asking about generating `using` directives automatically? If so, I think you may be missing a difference between assembly references and namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with Visual Studio, you might want to use the `Quick Actions` to include a missing namespace reference, either by right clicking on the type or by pressing `CTRL` + `.` and hitting `ENTER`:

[image]

This approach doesn't include all namespace references, but helps managing namespace references without adding `using` statements manually, while keeping your header as clean as possible.

Comment: That's the way it works. Typically, you do not want all usings in all classes/files but only the relevant ones. You might start with copy/pasting them all, and later on (once your code uses most features you actually need) you can use "remove and sort usings" to clean up.